# How to regexmatch a range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to take a data from a table and get the value of how much a class gets a point. I used VLOOKUP to do this, but the problem is that I have to tell the sheets on which class gets how much.

The data:

[image: The data]

Comment: What does it mean _"to tell the sheets on which class gets how much"_? Please, show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Your data seems to be setup in a way that unnecessarily complicates things.

`kelas`-column isn't showing the class, but name and class. For easy use in calculation this would better be divided in two columns: `name` | `class`

`poins`-column seems to be numbers formatted as text (judging by the leading `+`) if it was showing the number only and the class would show the actual class, a simple `SUMIF` would solve your problem.

Now it's still doable using `SUMPRODUCT`:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A17=RIGHT($B$2:$B$11,2)),--($D$2:$D$11))`

The first part checks if the search value `A17` equals the last 2 digits in range `B2:B11` (the `$`'s in the formula are to lock the range when dragging the formula down or aside).
This results in an array of TRUE's and FALSE's which is converted to 1's and 0's by the leading `--`.

The second part simply converts the text values to numbers using the same logic as with the TRUE's and FALSE's, using the `--`.

SUMPRODUCT multiplies the first array with the second array and adds it all up.
If a condition is true it multiplies the value of the points column by 1 (equals the points), if false it multiplies by 0 (equals 0).
In the end it sums all values meeting given condition.

[image]